# Unicode characters appearing in html on android webview

Tags: android, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

Attached screenshot is html rendered on my android device. Somehow there is a unicode character before paragraph text 'Where' and after the equation. I am not seeing any reference for that unicode character in css file or in html , need help to fix this.

[image]

```
                                                        <div class="mathkatex">{I_{{\rm{arc\_Voc}}}} = {10^{\left( {k1 + k2\lg {I_{{\rm{bf}}}} + k3\lg G}
                                                            \right)}}\left( {k4I_{{\rm{bf}}}^6 + k5I_{{\rm{bf}}}^5 + k6I_{{\rm{bf}}}^4 + k7I_{{\rm{bf}}}^3 +
                                                            k8I_{{\rm{bf}}}^2 + k9I_{{\rm{bf}}}^{} + k10} \right)</div>
                                                        < span class="label">
                                                            < strong> (1) < /strong> </span> < p> where </p>
```

Comment: Copy your html content into notepad or something similar, it will show you any hidden characters

Comment: For future reference - please also show any code samples you can so we can better help

Comment: @KodyR. i added a code snippet. Take a look and let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Pete i added html snippet to a text editor but that does not show any unicode character.